# Windows Phone Dashboard doesn't detect additional languages in our app, only english

Tags: localization, windows-phone-8.1

Our windows phone 8.1 app contains 15 languages. We used this article:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Adding_multilingual_support_to_your_Windows_Phone_application_using_the_Multilingual_App_Toolkit

to create resx files.

But we are using our own localization system and Dashboard doesn't detect any additional languages in our app.

According to the documentation:

"The language detection process includes the evaluation of the **metadata** that is used to describe the app and the UI text that is used within the app. "

Can someone please specify which exact files (metadata) and where we should put into our build to make the dashboard see the additional languages?

Answer (score 0):

The List of supported languages is added to the manifest and automatically generated when packaging. You can change it by hand in the manifest (open the xml, not the visual editor).

Change from:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
</Resources>
```

To:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="de-de"/>
  ...
</Resources>
```